# What is the meaning of "red dead"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

In a movie, a cat says

> I bring her a red dead bird. She throws it out. I bring her a red dead
>   mouse. Right in the garbage!

I think the word 'red' here means "covered in blood".
Please help me to understand it better. Thank you.

Comment: "Red dead" doesn't mean anything to me - your guess may be correct. It might help if you told us which movie.

Comment: All it means is that the colour of the thing is red. (A dead bird that was red.)  It says nothing about *why* it's red. Your interpretation my be correct, and may even be likely, but it's not obvious from the quoted sentences alone.